# Login function from UseContext react won't work

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I can't call Login function from my AuthContext. I checked everything but can't figure out what the problem is.

Login.js: I'm trying to call handleLogin from AuthContext, but nothing happens when I press the submit button.

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthContext";
import "./Login.css"

function Login() {
    let { handleLogin } = useContext(AuthContext)

    return (
        <div id="auth-page">
            <h1><a href="/">Blog</a></h1>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                <label>Username</label><br />
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" name="username" required></input><br />
                <label>Password</label><br />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password" required></input><br />
                <div className="btnHolder">
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

AuthContext.js:

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const AuthContext = createContext()
export default AuthContext;

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    let [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) : null)
    let [user, setUser] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) : null)
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const handleLogin = async (form, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3500/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            credentials: "include",
            body: JSON.stringify({'username':e.target.username.value, 'password':e.target.password.value})
        })
        const data = await res.json()
        if (res.status === 200) {
            setAccessToken(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data))
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken", JSON.stringify(data))
            navigate("/")
        } else {
            alert(data.error)
        }
    }

    const logoutUser = () => {
        setAccessToken(null)
        setUser(null)
        localStorage.removeItem("accessToken")
        navigate("/login")
    }

    const updateToken = async () => {
        let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3500/refresh", {
            method: "GET",
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
        })
        let data = await res.json()

        if (res.status === 200) {
            setAccessToken(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data["accessToken"]))
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken", JSON.stringify(data))
        } else {
            logoutUser()
        }

        if (loading) {
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    let contextData = {
        user:user,
        accessToken:accessToken,
        handleLogin:handleLogin,
        logoutUser:logoutUser,
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loading) {
            updateToken()
        }
        let fourMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 4
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (accessToken) {
                updateToken()
            }
        }, fourMinutes)
        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
    }, [accessToken, loading])

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData} >
            {loading ? null : children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

PrivateRoute.js:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component }) => {
    let { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
    return user ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './pages/Layout'
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import Register from './pages/Register/Register';
import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthContext';
import PrivateRoute from "./utils/PrivateRoute";
import './App.css'

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          
          <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<PrivateRoute component={Home} />} />
          </Route>

          <Route>
            <Route path='/login' element={<Login />}></Route>
            <Route path='/register' element={<Register />}></Route>
          </Route>

        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
export default App
```

Everything working fine except handleLogin function. Can someone figure out where the problem is?

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: no, there aren't.

Comment: The handleLogin method in the Authcontext should only accept one parameter and i.e the event itself ```const handleLogin = async (e)```. By doing this the method should be called.

Comment: @TirthTrivedi It still won't work.

Comment: Can you prepare a small working example on codesandbox?